# Codeigniter: adding label to foreach echo

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

This are my view code:

```
<?php
        foreach($books as $books) {
        echo $books->book_id;
        echo $books->book_name;
        echo $books->description;
        echo $books->author;
        echo $books->publisher;
        echo $books->pages;
        echo $books->publication_date;
        echo $books->price;
        echo $books->status;
        echo $books->quantity;
        echo $books->genres;
        echo $books->user_rating;
        echo $books->reviews;
        }
    ?>
```

the output is [image]

However i want the output to be like Book ID:1, Book Name:qweqweqweqweqwe, price 123.00 and so on, in a table form am i able to do it?

Comment: try somthing like this : echo "Book Name : " . $books->book_name . " <br>";

Comment: Just open table tag before loop close table tag after loop content inside loop wrap them in td tr

Comment: It will be better if you edit your question how you want to look like. If you want new line use `<br>` as @AdrienXL said. If you want see it inside table use @noufalcep solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you..

```
<table>
  <th>
    <td>Book Id</td>
    <td>Book Name</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td>Publisher</td>
    <td>Pages</td>
    <td>Publication Date</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>status</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Genres</td>
    <td>User Rating</td>
    <td>Reviews</td>
  </th>
  <?php foreach($books as $book) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $book->book_id ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->book_name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->description ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->author ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->publisher ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->pages ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->publication_date ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->price ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->status ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->quantity ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->genres ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->user_rating ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book->reviews ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

concat your string with php function.

```
echo "Book ID:".$books->book_id.", Book Name: ".$books->book_name;
```

Like this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
echo "Book ID : $books->book_id";
```

double quotes will automatically identify variables and execute them.

you can also try:-

```
echo 'Book ID:'. $books->book_id;
```

Please choose which one easily readable for you.